# How to update child entity when updating parent entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have two entities `Space` as parent and `SpaceInactivityDate` as child with relation `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToMany` and with `space_id` as a foreign key.
The `insert` operation works fine but when I tried to update, the `Space` table was updated but in the `SpaceInactivityDate` table instead of updating rows he added new lines. I have used the `CascadeType=All` and `cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE}` but usually I had the same result.

Space.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "space")
public class Space {

@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "space", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)   
private Set<SpaceInactivityDate> spaceInactivityDates = new HashSet<SpaceInactivityDate>();

// getters+setters
}
```

SpaceInactivityDate .java

```
@Table(name="space_incativity_date")
@Entity
public class SpaceInactivityDate {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "inactivity_start_date", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
@Type(type = "ec.ep.dit.sip.expomep.persistency.type.PersistentLocalDate")
private LocalDate inactivityStartDate;

@Column(name = "inactivity_end_date", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
@Type(type = "ec.ep.dit.sip.expomep.persistency.type.PersistentLocalDate")
private LocalDate inactivityEndDate;


@JoinColumn(name="space_id",referencedColumnName="id") 
@ManyToOne(optional=false,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Space space;

}
```

SpaceServiceImpl.java

```
this.spaceDao.save(space);
```

Comment: With JPA, you normally don't need to make any calls after updating an entity that's already persisted; you just use the setters and let the transaction complete.

Comment: set a breakpoint before save method and check the Set<SpaceInactivityDate> if members had no id fetch them from DB and set again if had id check the mode of Object to be persistant